# use clusterApply in snow package?

Tags: r, apply, snow

I'm trying to R code with snow package.
i have function

> imp<-function(x,y)

how can i use this function in clusterApply ?

```
cl <- makeCluster(c("localhost","localhost"), type = "SOCK")
clusterApply(cl, 1:6, get("+"), 3)
stopCluster(cl)
```

instead of this i want to use my function

```
cl <- makeCluster(c("localhost","localhost"), type = "SOCK")
clusterApply(cl, imp(dataset,3), 3)
stopCluster(cl)
```

suppose  this is my function how can i run in parallel and distributed system with this function..

```
impap<-function(x,y)
{
data<-as(x,"matrix")

t<-data+y

print(t)
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run it on multiple machines or parallel on multiple cores of the same machine?

Comment: @LucasFortini i think makecluster part will change when i use multiple machines ..am i right ?

Comment: @LucasFortini
 suppose this is my function how can i run in parallel multicore and distributed system with this function.. impap<-function(x,y) { data<-as(x,"matrix") t<-data+y print(t) }

Comment: @LucasFortini proj_name_root,working_dir what all these meant..please give a example with my code sir

Answer (score 1):

I tend to like snowfall for parallel and distributed computing. Here is a generic code that will parallelize well in both cases with minor modifications and that will also output log files for each instance along the way for better progress and error tracking.

```
rm(list = ls()) #remove all past worksheet variables
n_projs=5 #this is the number of iterations. Each of them gets sent to an available CPU core
proj_name_root="model_run_test"
proj_names=paste0(proj_name_root,"__",c(1:n_projs))

#FUNCTION TO RUN
project_exec=function(proj_name){
  cat('starting with', proj_name, '\n')
  ##ADD CODE HERE
  cat('done with ', proj_name, '\n')
}

require(snowfall)
# Init Snowfall with settings from sfCluster
cpucores=as.integer(Sys.getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'))

#TWO WAYS TO RUN (CLUSTER OR SINGLE MACHINE)
#hosts=c(commandArgs(TRUE)) #list of strings with computer names in cluster
sfInit(socketHosts=hosts, parallel=T, cpus=cpucores, type="SOCK", slaveOutfile="/home/cluster_user/output.log")

##BELOW IS THE CODE IF YOU ARE RUNNING PARALLEL IN THE SAME MACHINE (MULTI CORE)
#sfInit(parallel=T, cpus=cpucores) #This is where you would need to configure snowfall to create a cluster with the AWS instances 

#sfLibrary(sp) ##import libraries used in your function here into your snowfall instances
sfExportAll()
all_reps=sfLapply(proj_names,fun=project_exec)
sfRemoveAll()
sfStop()
```

Comment: what changes ll have made in this code for my project.?

Comment: can i add my code here?....sink(file(paste0(working_dir,proj_name,"_log.txt"), open="wt"))         #log progress into file
  cat('starting with', proj_name, '\n')
  ##ADD CODE HERE
  cat('done with ', proj_name, '\n')
  #Stop sinks

Comment: will you please give example instead of putting  name ?

Comment: suppose this is my function how can i run in parallel and distributed system with this function..

impap<-function(x,y)
{
data<-as(x,"matrix")

t<-data+y

print(t)
}

Comment: fun=project_exec what is meant by this ?>

Comment: sfApply, like many other parallel functions in r is based on application of a function to an array. So in this case, the first argument specifies the array and the second the function to apply it. As you have a function with two input arguments, in both sfApply (snowfall)  and clusterapply (snow) you can specify additional arguments. However, the other alternative is to call out the second arguments from within the function itself.

Comment: suppose this is my function how can i run in parallel and distributed system with this function.. impap<-function(x,y) { data<-as(x,"matrix") t<-data+y print(t) }

Comment: Frtini please give example with my code
impap<-function(x,y) { data<-as(x,"matrix") t<-data+y print(t) }

Comment: I have simplified the code to make it easier for you to understand. As I mentioned above, have your function written in a format as impap<-function(index, x_list,y_list) where index is used to pick an x and y to be used from lists. This way you can run it as all_reps=sfLapply(indexes,fun=project_exec, x_list, y_list).